# ASP.NET. Hiding whole site structure. Is it possible?

Tags: asp.net, directory-structure, directory-listing

I guess all everybody else would like the opposite but i need to hide the "directory" structure of an ASP.NET website.

For this reason i am thinking of

1. Use the robots.txt as follows...

   User-agent: * 
   Disallow: /
2. Use Url rewriting, to make ghost paths
3. Disable directory browsing. (Directory listing denied...)
4. Use .ashx to serve images.
5. Other ways that you may suggest.

In other words i would not like someone with a "downloader-structrure reader", strip my site.

As you see the sekurity tag is missing :)

P.S. I do not care about SEO

Comment: To clarify: you're trying to prevent robots from crawling your site, yet allow real visitors to browse about?

Comment: @ajreal: The last time i used ASP was related to IIS!

Comment: @Richard: I would like to prevent robots from crawling but allow real visitors to browse my site, only through the links. The users should not know for example that i have an "/images" directory.

Comment: add in basic access authentication if u using apache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A site downloader like `wget -r` will work anyway. It follows links and doesn't care about directories (except the fact that you can limit the depth). If you want to exclude legit crawlers like Google, using robots.txt is fine. wget and rogue crawlers don't care about it though.

The only really good solution is either requriring a login (but that still doesn't protect you against those people who'd just use wget to download your whole site; they'll just provide it with the login information/session id) or cluttering your content with annoying CAPTCHAs (pisses of legit users quickly) or making the whole site use JavaScript/AJAX to display/load content. That makes the user experience even better (if it's done properly) and effectively locks out most/all crawlers.

Comment: Thanks! By the way you have a great username!

Comment: Haha, I have that username for a decade now.. the first place I needed a nickname was a forum about the Thief2 game - and since that I've never changed it. ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you want users to be able to browse your site, you're obviously going to need links to other pages. To (attempt to) make these links difficult for a crawler, you could try rendering all your links dynamically in javascript. This means a robot which doesn't do full DOM rendering like a browser wont be able to extract the links. However of course someone *could* take a look at your site and build something which does parse out the links if they were so inclined.

With respects to hiding directory structure from users and/or bots, then yes you'll have to implement some kind of url rewriting:

```
Outbound: /assets/images/image.jpg -> /somecode.jpg
Inbound:  /somecode.jpg -> /assets/images/image.jpg
```

Else they'll be able to inspect links (whether static or dynamically rendered) in their browser and determine directory structure.